# Forcing FileNotFoundException

Tags: java, junit, testing, ioexception, filenotfoundexception

I'm writing a test for a piece of code that has an IOException catch in it that I'm trying to cover. The try/catch looks something like this:

```
try {
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(cacheFileName));
} catch (IOException e) {
    LOGGER.error("Bad news!", e);
} finally {
```

The easiest way seems to make FileOutputStream throw a FileNotFoundException, but perhaps I'm going about this all the wrong way.

Anyone out there have any tips?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From your comment:

> Yes, I suppose the question should
>   really have been "How do I create a
>   file that does not exist on both Linux
>   and Windows?" On windows, I can use
>   'new File("X:/")', where X: is a drive
>   letter that does not exist. On Linux,
>   this does not work because that is a
>   valid file name.

Look at java.io.File.createTempFile.  Use it to create the file and then delete it.

Probably pass it something like:

```
File tempFile;

tempFile = createTempFile(getClass().getName(), 
                          Long.toString(System.currentTimeMillis());
tempFile.delete();
```

That should give you a unique name in a platform indendent manner that you can safely use without (much) fear of it existing.

Comment: Thanks. I had tried that earlier but it seemed like the FileOutputStream was auto-creating the file. Turns out I had a "helper" method used in the test that auto-created the file.

Comment: File.createTempFile("prefix", "suffix") will always create an unique file (for the JVM execution) no matter how many times it's called with the same arguments.
So you don't need to worry about specifying an unique name when invoking that method.

Comment: That is what I figured... I just couldn't be 100% sure given the javadoc.

Comment: IF you want to absolutely ensure the file doesn't get created by another test:  As a refinement, instead of deleting the temp file, grab an exclusive lock on it using RandomAccessFile (in rw mode), then getChannel().lock().  Be sure to unlock() and delete in a finally block at the end of your test.

Comment: @Kevin Isn't that platform dependent though?  On Unix file locking is advisory while on Windows it is mandatory.

Answer (score 5):

You could set `cacheFileName` to an invalid name or to one you know doesn't exist.

Comment: Yes, I suppose the question should really have been "How do I create a file that does not exist on both Linux and Windows?"

On windows, I can use 'new File("X:/")', where X: is a drive letter that does not exist. On Linux, this does not work because that is a valid file name.

Comment: Use a character that is invalid for files like * or ?.

Answer (score 2):

There are two parts to any test: getting it to happen and measuring that you got the correct result.

### Fault Injection

The easiest answer is the one that's already been mentioned, which is to set `cacheFileName` to a file that will never exist. This is likely the most practical answer in this situation.

However, to cause an arbitrary condition such as an `IOException`, what you really want is [Fault Injection](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fault_injection). This forces faults in your code without forcing you to instrument your source code. Here are a few methods for doing this:

- **Mock objects** You could use a factory method to create an overridden `ObjectOutputStream` or `FileOutputStream`. In test code the implementation would throw an `IOException` when you wanted to, and in production code would not modify the normal behavior.
- **Dependency Injection** In order to get your Mock Object in the right place you could use a framework such as [Spring](http://www.springsource.org/) or [Seam](http://www.seamframework.org/) to "inject" the appropriate object into the class that's doing the work. You can see that these frameworks even have a priority for objects that will be injected, so that during unit testing you can override the production objects with test objects.
- **[Aspect Oriented Programming](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Aspect-oriented_programming)** Instead of changing the structure of your code at all, you can use AOP to inject the fault in the right place. For instance, using [AspectJ](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/) you could define a [Pointcut](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html#pointcuts) where you wanted the exception to be thrown from, and have the [Advice](http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/doc/released/progguide/starting-aspectj.html#advice) throw the desired exception.

There are other answers to fault injection on Java; for instance a product called [AProbe](http://www.ocsystems.com/tech_aprobe.html) pioneered what could be called AOP in C long ago, and they also have a Java product.

### Validation

Getting the exception thrown is a good start, but you also have to validate that you got the right result. Assuming that the code sample you have there is correct, you want to validate that you logged that exception. Someone above mentioned using a Mock object for your logger, which is a viable option. You can also use AOP here to catch the call to the logger.

I assume that the logger is [log4j](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/); to solve a similar problem, I implemented my own log4j appender which captures log4j output: I specifically capture only `ERROR` and `FATAL`, which are likely to be the interesting log messages in such a case. The appender is referenced in `log4j.xml` and is activated during the test run to capture error log output. This is essentially a mock object, but I didn't have to restructure all my code that got a log4j `Logger`.

Answer (score 0):

> I'm writing a test for a piece of code
>   that has an IOException catch in it
>   that I'm trying to cover.

I'm not entirely sure I understand your goal, but if you want to test if the exception is thrown, you can tell the test you expect it to throw the exception:

```
@Test(expected=IOException.class)
```

Your test will then fail if the exception is not thrown, and succeed if it is thrown (like, if the `cacheFileName` file does not exist).

Answer (score 0):

A FileNotFoundException would obviously trigger the catch. The javadoc states the cases where it will be thrown.

You should also consider that the ObjectOutputStream constructor can throw an IOException so may want to cover this case in your tests.

Answer (score 0):

Two easy ways would be either set cacheFileName to a non-existent file or set the specified file to read-only access.

-John

Answer (score 0):

As the code is currently written, you could try to mock out the error() call on the LOGGER object and check to see if it gets called when you expect an IOException.

Your desire to test may have uncovered a fundamental problem with the code as it's written. An error is occurring but there's no boolean or flag value (set the filename to a special pattern) that provides other sections of code to determine if writing to the file was successful. If this is contained in a function, maybe you could return a boolean or set an object level variable.

Answer (score 0):

```
cacheFileName = "thisFileShouldNeverExistAndIfItDoesYouAreScrewingUpMyTests";
```

Sure you could take steps and jump thru hoops to programatically make sure that the file name will never, ever, ever exist, or you could use a String that will never exist in 99.99999% of cases.

Answer (score 0):

I hope this is what you meant.

```
if(new File(cachedFile).exists()) {
    oos = new ObjectOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(cacheFileName));
    //do your code here
} else {
    throw new FileNotFoundException("File doesn't exist!");
}
```

Comment: This make no sense. FileOutputStream create a file. To check if the file exists make no sense if the op want create a file.